# How to make hover css menu fade in and out?

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list menu in my header that has submenus on parent list items.
I've been trying to set the :hover pseudo-class to make the submenus fade in and out when moving the cursor over the links.

The problem is that I can only make them fade in, so when I move the cursor away they don't fade out, they just disappear instantly.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I've included a second jsfiddle below in which I've managed to achieve the effect I want with some simpler html.

Example 1: https://jsfiddle.net/ornbovv7/2/

Example 2: https://jsfiddle.net/aou6j8gz/1/

My code:

```
.header {
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#fff;
}

.content {
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
  background-color:pink;
}

nav.main-menu ul {
  position:relative;
  top:30px;
  list-style:none;
}

nav.main-menu ul li {
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px 30px 10px 30px;
  padding:0px 20px 45px 20px;
}

nav.main-menu ul ul {
  position:absolute; 
  left:-999em;
  width:175px;
  display:block; 
  height:auto;
  margin:40px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding:0;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), 0 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  background-color:#ffffff;
  opacity:0;

  transition: left 0s ease 0.6s, opacity 0.6s ease 0s;
}

nav.main-menu ul li:hover ul {
  left:auto;
  opacity:0.9;
  transition: left 0s ease 0s, opacity 0.6s ease 0s;
}

nav.main-menu ul ul li {
  position:relative;
  float: none;
  padding: 7px 10px 7px 10px;
}

nav.main-menu ul ul li a {
  display:inline-block;
}


<header class="header">

    <nav class="main-menu">
        <div>
            <ul id="menu-header-menu-1" class="menu">

                <li>link 1</li>

                <li>link 2
                     <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li>sublink 1</li>
                        <li>sublink 2</li>
                        <li>sublink 3</li>
                        <li>sublink 4</li>
                        <li>sublink 5</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>link 3
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </nav>

</header>
```

Comment: Not too sure how to fix but the problem is with the positioning. Th left is returning instantly to -999em which is making it appear as if the transition is not working. It's working, just off the screen..Hmmm. Hope that at least helps identify the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

left -9999em and auto cannot take a transitions . auto is not a number.

You can avoid this using pointer-events and drop the left coordonates:https://jsfiddle.net/ornbovv7/3/

```
nav.main-menu ul li ul {
  position:absolute; 
  width:175px;
    display:block; 
    height:auto;
    margin:40px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding:0;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), 0 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background-color:#ffffff;
  opacity:0;
    pointer-events:none;
    transition: opacity 0.6s ease 0s;
}

nav.main-menu ul li:hover ul {
  left:auto;
  pointer-events:auto;
  opacity:0.9;
  transition:  opacity 0.6s ease 0s ;
}
```

or use left:0; and li in relative position : https://jsfiddle.net/ornbovv7/4/
**beside you do need to give a delay for the left transition, so it fades away before to go off the screen area**

```
nav.main-menu ul li {
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px 30px 10px 30px;
  padding:0px 20px 45px 20px;
  position:relative;
}

nav.main-menu ul ul {
  position:absolute; 
  left:-999em;
  width:175px;
    display:block; 
    height:auto;
    margin:40px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding:0;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), 0 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background-color:#ffffff;
  opacity:0;

    transition: left 0s ease 0.6s, opacity 0.6s ease 0s;
}

nav.main-menu ul li:hover ul {
  left:0;
  opacity:0.9;
  transition: left 0s ease 1s, opacity 0.6s ease 0s;
}
```

Comment: These were both great answers, thank you. I've chosen this one as the accepted answer because of the pointer events rule, which I hadn't even heard of before. I've managed to get this to work now :)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to take advantage of the `:not` pseudo tag, in combination with the `:hover`. I wrote an article a few years ago on a similar example - [you can read it here](https://coderwall.com/p/xybujw/create-a-list-hover-effect-to-highlight-elements-using-pure-css) if you're interested.

I was able to get your first example to work by adding the following:

```
nav.main-menu ul li:not(:hover) ul {
  left:auto;
  opacity:0;
  transition: left 0s ease 0s, opacity 0.6s ease 0s;
}
```

[Here is a link to the forked fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/cs4c9Lgn/)

Hope I understood the question and goal correctly.

Comment: Point your mouse under the bar nav ... and you will see the big area now triggers de event

Comment: idem for Motjaba example, the sublist shows up when you hover its area in the pink area :p

Comment: Thanks mwielbut, the article was an interesting read - I'd seen something similar on a hifi website very recently and wondered how they created that effect with the links :)